# Does __TABLES__ view in BigQuery give the right information

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm witnessing strange behaviour in BigQuery and I'm hoping someone can explain it. If I query the `__TABLES__` view to find out row counts then it tells me there is no data in my tables:

```sql
select dataset_id,table_id,row_count
from `jamiet_dp_event_service.__TABLES__`
where table_id like '%pageRequest%'
order by row_count desc
```

[image]

However, if I query one of those tables directly then it does have data in it:

```sql
select count(*) from `jamiet_dp_event_service.pageRequest_1_all_v1`
```

[image]

Either I'm losing my marbles or the `__TABLES__` view doesn't do what it purports to do.

The data is being streamed into these tables via a Dataflow job the way, not that that should matter I don't think.

Can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: The `__TABLES__` show the physical rows in the table. Therefore views and external tables and linked tables to Sheets do not show any rows. Also if the data is freshly inserted it may not be in the table yet.

Comment: I can confirm this is a physical table, as you can see from my screenshot the table DOES appear in the `__TABLES__`, its the row_count value that is wrong.

Comment: I have just checked again and can confirm that `__TABLES__` is indeed now (about two hours later) displaying the correct rowcounts. I previously waited many minutes (the time it took to write my post above) and `__TABLES__` was still showing zero for the table in question, I guess I should be prepared to wait a significant amount of time for `__TABLES__` to be accurate.